# autofill dropdown after onclick autocomplete

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I want to know how I can go about writing a code that will autofill my dropdown after I click a name on my autocomplete search field. The drop downs can work ohk. Here's a picture for a better understanding.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use Javascript to update the dropdown value on [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event of search field

```
$( "#search" ).blur(function() {
  //update dropdown value here
});
```